# Adding custom masks to phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So i'm creating a simple function to mask phone numbers. My phone numbers have a 9 digits and i want `preg_replace` them with a given mask like `2-2-2-1-2` or `3-2-2-2` and etc.

I tried this:

```
$mask = explode('-', '3-2-2-2');

$pattern = '';
$replace = '';

foreach ($mask as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        $pattern = '/\(?(\d{' . $value . '})\)?[- ]';
        $replace = '$' . ++$key . '-';
        continue;
    }

    if ($key == count($mask) - 1) {
        $pattern .= '?(\d{' . $value . '})/';
        $replace .= '$' . ++$key;
        break;
    }

    $pattern .= '?(\d{' . $value . '})[- ]';
    $replace .= '$' . ++$key . '-';
}


return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, '902000810');
```

and the result is `902-00-08-10`. Sometimes getting error `preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found`. How can i refactor this to not getting errors?

Comment: What are sample inputs and expected outputs? What is wrong with the code? What input results in the error? Please provide a working minimal example of code that we could run  and see where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
$num = '902000810';
$mask = explode('-', '3-2-2-2');
```

There're other ways than using regex to format a phone number from the mask.

- using formatted strings:

  ```
  $maskPH = array_map(fn($i) => "%{$i}s", $mask);
  $formatI = implode('', $maskPH);
  $formatO = implode('-', $maskPH);

  $result = vsprintf($formatO, sscanf($num, $formatI));
  ```
- using `unpack`:

  ```
  $format = array_reduce($mask, function ($c, $i) {
      static $j = 0;
      return "{$c}A{$i}_" . $j++ . "/";
  });

  $result = implode('-', unpack($format, $num));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found`
means that your pattern does not terminate with a `/` as last character.

But all three patterns lack proper formatting:

You should modify them accordingly.

From:

`$pattern = '/\(?(\d{' . $value . '})\)?[- ]';`

`$pattern .= '?(\d{' . $value . '})/';`

`$pattern .= '?(\d{' . $value . '})[- ]';`

To:

`$pattern = '/\(?(\d{' . $value . '})\)?[- ]/';`

`$pattern .= '/?(\d{' . $value . '})/';`

`$pattern .= '/?(\d{' . $value . '})[- ]/';`